# Migrating Amazon RDS MySQL 5.6 to Amazon Auroa MySQL 5.7 Through AWS DMS

Tags: migration, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

As the title of this topic is quite self-explanatory, The issue I am facing is that I am using "Ongoing Replication" as a replication type and everything is going well. Except for migrating the MySQL DB users, AWS DMS is unable to do that. Could you please guide us to a most effective solution with minimum downtime, and it would be great if there is no downtime. I have so far explored few options like creating an aurora replica from RDS MySQL DB (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-create-an-amazon-aurora-read-replica-from-a-mysql-db-instance/). Or Exporting the DB users from snapshot stored on the S3 bucket (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.html#AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.S3).
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an Aurora replica for RDS MySQL is the AWS suggested way for RDS to Aurora migration with minimal downtime: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.RDSMySQL.Replica.html

You don't need to use AWS DMS at all. The high level steps are:

- Create a Aurora RR (MySQL 5.6) from RDS MySQL 5.6
- Upgrade the Aurora RR to 5.7
- Ensure Replica lag is zero from master to new Aurora 5.7 replica
- Promote the new Aurora MySQL 5.7

Comment: Thanks man, I already figured this out. and Its the best available solution :)